# TextBox horizontal-scroll bug

Tags: c#, winforms, winapi, textbox

There appears to be a bug in the Win32 edit control that WinForms.TextBox wraps:

1. Open Notepad.
2. Make sure that the bottom scrollbar is visible (you may have to turn off word wrapping).
3. Enter a long line, so that the bottom scrollbar activates.
4. Delete some of this text, so that the line becomes much smaller.

Now the bottom scrollbar doesn't update to reflect the fact that the line is now much smaller.

In fact, even if you resize the window, the scrollbar still seems to think that we have a huge line.  The only work-around seems to be enabling and disabling word wrapping.

Can anyone suggest a way to fix this from a WinForms .NET app?

Comment: Toggling WordWrap is the sledgehammer solution, it causes the native window to be recreated.  You can tell from the flicker.  This is one of the built-in, erm, behaviors that you shouldn't try to fix.

Comment: +1 for mentioning a bug that is (I think) as old as Windows notepad is. This one could beat all WinRunner and QTP bug that I considered the longest-lasting bugs ever.

Answer (score 0):

Another workaround is when the additional text is deleted .. cut the remaining text and then paste it again. That makes scroll bar disappear.

You can hit CTRL+A to select all text then CTRL+X to cut and CTRL+V to paste.

Just an idea.

Comment: You can do this a bit more efficiently (and without interfering with the clipboard) by doing textbox.Text = textbox.Text. However, there's a bunch of problems with this approach: selection, caret position,  current horizontal and vertical scroll position and the ability to undo are all lost. Some of these could be saved and restored, however.